# Looking for something to monitor an Internet Shared Connection in Windows XP

Tags: networking, bandwidth, monitoring, workstation, ics

If someone knows any software with these features:

- Works from the tray area
- Very lightweight
- Works also in Windows XP (preferably workstation, nothing serverish required)
- Can show a bandwidth usage graph, where I can easily see each PC's usage
- I can inspect a computer's connections, find out the ports and applications that are using them (eg, all bandwidth is consumed by PC #3, that's running uTorrent.exe from port 33003)

...I'd happily check it out. I'm only sharing my connection with (at most) four computers - I'd prefer not having to add hardware or reinstall my system.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [`Microsoft Network Monitor 3.3`](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=983b941d-06cb-4658-b7f6-3088333d062f&displaylang=en) would work if you played around with it?

Answer (score 0):

May be useful

- DUMeter http://www.dumeter.com/
- TMerer http://tmeter.ru/tmeter/ (i found only russian site, but english interface presented) (for up to 3 filters free) tmtAnalyser - http://tmeter.ru/tmanlog/ allow analyse detail tmeter log.

Network analysers (sniffer) is good for troubleshooting. But collect too detail information for continous usage.

Answer (score 0):

You could use wireshark for some in depth analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Spiceworks](http://www.spiceworks.com/). It is free and I am pretty sure it can do everything you want so long as you have SNMP turned on at all of your switches.